# Setting cookies to chrome running in headless mode

Tags: google-chrome, headless

I am planning to use chrome.exe to take a png snapshot of a web page.
The web page has references to js files that are served by an application server. Application server needs session cookies to authrize and server the pages.

I could not find any options to pass cookies to chrome.ext.

I have searched in google, but most suggestions are pointing to use selenium web driver. Making use of selenium web driver for chrome is making me choose compatible versions only. I have to frequently update the driver if the chrome version changes. It is not acceptable for my use case.

Executing the command mentioned below using java process builder. 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe "   -headless -hide-scrollbars -disable-gpu -screenshot=C:\Users\abc\Desktop\tmp\file1.png C:/Users/abc/test.html

I need a way to pass cookies without using any third party libraries (webdriver, puppeteer etc..)